Using custom emoji in the selection list
picture
I want to add the server custom emoji in the selection list.
I think the format is correct. But it isn't show up correctly.
        view = TicketTypeSelectView(ticket_data['ticket_types'])
        await interaction.response.send_message("Please select the type of ticket you want to create:", view=view, ephemeral=True, delete_after=60.0)


class TicketTypeSelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, ticket_types):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        options = []
        for name, data in ticket_types.items():
            emoji = data.get('emoji', '')  # Retrieve the emoji if available
            options.append(discord.SelectOption(label=f"{emoji} {name}", value=name))
        self.add_item(TicketTypeSelect(options))

This is my JSON:
        "TruckersMP Event": {
            "staff_role_ids": [
                1269190673492607078
            ],
            "ticket_category_id": 1267312898217218128,
            "ticket_name": "TruckersMP Event",
            "emoji": "<:ProEvent:1274673606239981598>"
        }


You simply forgot to add the emoji parameter :D
options.append(discord.SelectOption(label=f"{emoji} {name}", value=name, emoji=emoji))


Solved! Thanks for helping!

No problem, Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you
